# Letting users write to a list

Tags: c++, arrays, list, vector

I am new to C++ and am trying to make a program to allow whoever is running the program to write to a list, and when they are done typing "exit" and it will display the list. I am lost on how to achieve this, could anyone help?

Here is what I have :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string uid;
    write(1,"\E[H\E[2J",7);
    cout << "Enter UID: ";
    cin >> uid;
    cout << "DB: \n\n" << uid << " \n\n""end\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

How I could I put that in a loop such that they each could keep writing to the list until they type "exit"?

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop?

Comment: What is '\E'?  Perhaps this should be '\x1B'?

Comment: Those are ascii escape characters I used to clear the terminal window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question doesn't show much effort, I'll give a complicated answer you have no chance of understanding...

```
std::vector<std::string> list;
for(std::string i; std::cin >> i && i != "exit"; list.push_back(i));
std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

.. But is possibly the smallest way to do it (I'm sure someone will make a smaller one now that I said that)

Answer (score 3):

There's a list in the std - `std::list`. Look it up. There are functions for inserting elements into it and you can iterate through it at the end to print the values.

The loop is as easy as

```
do{
    //whatever you want to do in the loop
    //read input
    //insert into list
}while(/*condition*/); //condition should be something like
                       //the string is not "exit"
```

`std::string` has methods to compare to other strings and also overloaded operators. Finding the ones to use can serve as a good exercise for you.

Actual code not given because... well, that wouldn't help you that much, would it?

Comment: Athough there's no real reason to prefer ``std::list`` over ``std::vector`` here.

Comment: @juanchopanza well, it's part of the requirement, but that's about it. :)

Comment: thanks, looking it up. But the "actual code" would be very helpful. Thanks for your speedy response

Comment: @user1995298 no, you *think* it would be helpful, but it wouldn't.

Comment: I'm not sure OP really means ``std::list``. Might be an occasion to mention that in most cases it isn't such a good choice.

Comment: When I said list, I said that not knowing they technical version. Doesn't have to necessarily be std::list, just whatever would achieve the task in the best way.

Comment: @user1995298 then use a `std::vector` as juanchopanza suggested.